# cannot find cap command when using Rubber with Vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, vagrant, rubber

I want to test out a cluster built with Rubber using Vagrant. I followed the instructions on the Rubber Wiki but when I run `vagrant up staging` I get the following error:

```
[staging] -- /vagrant
[staging] Running provisioner: rubber...
bundler: command not found: cap
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
bundler: command not found: cap
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
bundler: command not found: cap
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

This is my Vagrant configuration:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define :staging do |stg|
    stg.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.70.10"

    stg.vm.provision :rubber do |rubber|
      rubber.rubber_env = 'staging'

      rubber.rvm_ruby_version = 'ruby-2.0.0-p195'
    end
  end


  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "precise32"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
end
```

I have capistrano in my Gemfile and it is installed. I've also managed to create a staging instance on EC2, but I can't figure out why it isn't working with Vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues today and could get it working by running "**bundle**" on my local machine.

Comment: I see, I'm also having hard times working with rubber+vagrant, looks like it's missing a good doc/guide about them and a FAQ as well.